# Which function describes the following relation?

Tags: functions

Supplementing my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215487/what-function-is-it) I decided to ask a new one which is more general.

So is given a natural even number $k$ and a function $f_k:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_0:n\rightarrowtail(n \;\text{mod} \; k) \rightarrowtail \text{miracle} \rightarrowtail f_k(n)$ such that:

Here comes the miracle explanation (how functions acts):

- $k = 2$

  ```
  0 -> 0
  1 -> 0
  ```
- $k = 4$

  ```
  0 -> 0
  1 -> 1
  2 -> 1
  3 -> 0
  ```
- $k = 6$

  ```
  0 -> 0
  1 -> 1
  2 -> 2
  3 -> 2
  4 -> 1
  5 -> 0
  ```
- $k = 8$

  ```
  0 -> 0
  1 -> 1
  2 -> 2
  3 -> 3
  4 -> 3
  5 -> 2
  6 -> 1
  7 -> 0
  ```

If $k$ would be odd, it would be simple: $$f(n) = |\frac{k}{2}  - |n - \frac{k}{2}|\;|$$ (fraction without decimal part). But for even $k$'s I can't figure out something, so could you please help me to express this function (must be something with modulo, absolute value, Gauss brackets of kind of this).

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use $(k-1)/2$ instead of $k/2$:
$$f(n)=\Bigg\lvert\frac{k-1}2-\bigg\lvert n-\frac{k-1}2\bigg\rvert\Bigg\rvert.$$